# Pointers for int and Arrays

Tags: c++, pointers

Hello i'm a noob in programming, i have a small doubt regarding pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myAge = 16;
    int* agePtr = &myAge;

    cout << "address of pointer" << agePtr << "Data at memory address" << *agePtr << endl;

    int badNums[5] = {4, 13, 14, 24, 34};
    int* numArrayPtr = badNums;

    cout<< "address" << numArrayPtr << "value" << *numArrayPtr << endl;

    numArrayPtr++;

    cout<< "address" << numArrayPtr << "value" << *numArrayPtr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

- In the first case while pointing an integer i use `&myAge` where as in
  the second case of incrementing Arrays if i use `&badNums` the compiler
  is returning an error, but if i use `badNums` its compiling why should
  we use `badNums` instead of `&badNums` in the second case?
- how can I increment the value in integer using pointers?

Comment: Because it is an array, when you assign it to your pointer, you are actually pointing to the first element. "array references decay into pointers". Source: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html

Comment: there are quite different opinions on this, but as a matter of fact as a beginner you can ignore pointers and c-style arrays almost completely for quite some time and turn to more interesting stuff. Imho the concepts of containers and iterators is much more essential to understanding c++ than going through all the trouble with pointers and c-style arrays

Answer (score 2):

Arrays implicitly decay to pointers, as per the rules of c++. There are many [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) in c++, this is one of them. When assigning an array to a pointer, it provides you with a pointer to the first element in the array.

Taking the address of an array (`&badNums`) will yield a pointer *to the array*, not to the first element. Array pointers are slightly more complicated and encode the size of the array in the type. The correct type for that assignment would be `int (*numArrayPtr)[5] = &badNums;` where `numArrayPtr` is a pointer to an array of 5 `int`s.

To increment a value pointer to by a pointer, you must first dereference that pointer using `operator *` just like if you wanted to read from or write to that value. It would look like `(*numArrayPtr)++;`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, using `&myAge` refers to the address of that integer value. The reason why you must use `badNums` instead of `&badNums` when doing assignment to the integer pointer is because `badNums` is already an integer pointer. Arrays implicitly decay into pointers, so using `&badNums` in that assignment would work if you were doing:

```
    int **numArrayPtr = &badNums;
```

which is just a pointer to a pointer to the address of `badNums`. So,

```
    int *numArrayPtr = badNums;
```

just means that we have a pointer to the address of `badNums`.

When we have an integer pointer like this, you can increment the value of each integer in the array by doing this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
          numArrayPtr[i]++;
    }
```

or, we can do the same thing without using array notation:

```
    for (int *i = numArrPtr; i != numArrPtr + 5; i++){
          (*numArrPtr)++; 
    }
```

I hope that answers your questions fully.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a small doubt regarding pointers

Just like `i` in `badnums[i]` is an *index* within array `badnums[]`, a *pointer* is an *index* to something stored in memory. Since any variable is stored in memory, you can access the contents of a variable with a pointer to whatever it contains (which is what languages implicitly do when using variables in your code).

The difference is that with pointers you must know the type of what the pointer designates, while an *index* uses the known type of the indexed elements of the variable it points to... because sooner than later you *will* iterate the contents of some known variable using a pointer.